# attempting to save FuncAnimation changes the animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, ffmpeg, jupyter-notebook

I am attempting to create and save an animation of a time-varying vector field using matplotlib's FuncAnimation.  When I run the animation without attempting to save it, it updates smoothly as expected.  However, when I try to save the animation, the vectors increase in length and the animation only appears to update a few times.  I've been able to record the screen to get a video file, but I'd like to understand how to save the animation to a video in python.

Here is the code to create the vector field animation.  I ran this in a local jupyter notebook using python 3.9.12 on Windows.

```
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

x_min, x_max = -20, 20
y_min, y_max = 0, 25
wire_x = -4
wire_y = 17

# Define the vector field function (example: rotating vector field)
def vector_field(x, y, t):
    x = x - wire_x
    y = y - wire_y
    r = np.sin(t) / (x**2 + y**2)
    u = -r * y
    v = r * x
    return (u, v)

# Define grid
x = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, 20)
y = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, 20)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Create animation
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_xlim(x_min, x_max)
ax.set_ylim(y_min, y_max)
ax.set_xlabel('X (m)')
ax.set_ylabel('Y (m)')

u, v = vector_field(X, Y, 1)

quiver = ax.quiver(X, Y, u, v)

time_arr = np.linspace(0,20,200)

plt.show()

def update_quiver(num):
    t = num * 0.1  # Time step
    u, v = vector_field(X, Y, t)
    quiver.set_UVC(u, v)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_quiver, frames=200, interval=50, repeat=False)
```

This produces an animation whose vectors smoothly vary in length on my computer.

However, when I try to save the animation by adding the lines

```
writervideo = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=60) 
ani.save('field_leftWire.mp4', writer=writervideo)
```

then the animation changes - the vectors are much longer and it appears to only update a few times throughout the animation.

I'll also note that I had to install ffmpeg and restart my computer as outlined in [Installation of FFMPEG for Python in WIndows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29760718/installation-of-ffmpeg-for-python-in-windows) to get the last two lines to run without error.